# Always getting all the records from child table in One to Many JPA Unidirectional Mapping

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have two entities

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PARENT")
public class Parent {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID", nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name= "NAME", nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="parentid", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Set<Child> child = new HashSet<>();

}


@Entity
@Table(name = "Child")
public class Child {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID", nullable = false)
    private Long id;


    @Column(name= "childname", nullable = false)
    private String childName;

    @Column(name= "Age", nullable = false)
    private Integer childAge;

}
```

ParentRepository :

```
List<Parent> findByNameAndChildChildName(String parentName, String childName);
```

Tables Data:
Parent

id | name

1. Test1
2. Test2

Child

id |  parentid |  childname  | age

1. ```
   1       Test1First   20
   ```
2. ```
   1       Test1Second  15
   ```
3. ```
   2       Test2First   25
   ```
4. ```
   2       Test2Second  21
   ```

So while fetching with above JPA repository always getting data of both child's

But expectation is to get the child data only for which condition satisfied as name/Age is provided.

Is there any way to implement it, we need to implement unidirectional relationship and there is no static where clause and data needs to be picked dynamically.

Comment: Your expectations are wrong - you are fetching parent entities, not children. Filtering affects the results returned, not what is within those results. JPA returned managed entities, so what you see is the state of that entity in the database - with all its children - allowing it to track changes made to the entity and synchronize that state to the DB. If it returned partial data based on filters, Parent1 would have a different view than Parent1' and Parent1'' and be difficult to ever merge or synchronize to the DB. If you want filtered children, query for them directly.

Comment: Can you show us what values you are passing into `findByNameAndChildChildName` for the listed output?

Comment: @EricGeorge, i am passing like findByNameAndChildChildName(Test1, Test1Second).

Comment: And need a response like
Parent(id=1, name=Test1 , child=[Child(id=2, childname=Test1Second, Age=15)])

Comment: From what you have shown us, it should be giving you `Parent(id=1, name=Test1 , child=[Child(id=2, childName=Test1Second, age=15), Child(id=1, childName=Test1First, age=20])` Your query method is returning parent objects, but has no way to apply a filter to the children joined through the `child` join. Of course, that still doesn't explain why you are seeing both parents.

Comment: Try adding `@ManyToOne() Parent parent;` to the `Child` class and adding `mappedBy="parent"` to the `@OneToMany` annotation in `Parent`.